# How can I match the URL in Chrome Extension like: *://foo.*/*

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

It doesn't work in content_scripts matches!

Is there other way to realize?

Comment: Please post the exact regex you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by setting `matches: "<all_urls>"` and narrowing this down with an [`include_globs`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#match-patterns-globs) directive set to `*://foo.*/*`.

***However***, be aware it might not do exactly what you want. Here are a few URLs that will match your glob pattern `*://foo.*/*`:

```
http://foo.com/bar
http://foo.google.com/
http://foo.any.domain.that.startswith.that.subdomain.com/bar/egg
```

Also, if you had a fixed string at the end, like `*://foo.*/bar` you could have further trouble:

```
http://foo.com/bar
http://foo.domain.matched.by.the.star.com/this/path/is/matched/by/the/star/bar
```

Comment: **This is what I want! Thank you so much! I should read the official doc carefully :'(**

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Match patterns doc](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html), this is not supported.

Comment: yeah and I think so... should I ony through JS to recognize the URL?